# Post apocalyptic movie set in apartment building

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, post-apocalyptic

I have not had luck in horror.com, reddit, quora, or yahoo, but will still try for this one and another movie

There is only light outside, a blinding light, anyone that goes into the light never comes back, there are survivors bunkered down in an apartment building(one of those large buildings in suburban areas, that are several buildings interconnected by a sort of bridge between them

There are a couple of guys that struggle for control of the group, the de facto leader ATM is a guy that, as I remember thinking, was going crazy, whenever he had an issue he needed to think about, he went to another floor, to some sort of maintenance room were he chatted with a chubby guy, nerdy looking, with glasses, and he "helped" him see things clearer

The group sent "scouts" to other parts of the buildings to get supplies, the run that we see on screen goes wrong and one of the monsters inside the light takes one of them away, after a fight and some deaths, there are only(As far as I remember) a father, his daughter, in her twenties, and the MC, they have a discussion and the father and daughter decide they will go into the light because, as they see it now, it might be a way to paradise, talking as if they were dead, instead of the rest of the world, and the light being the holy light to heaven, or something like that

I really want to see it again as I was working at the time and could not see everything and never got it's name, nor have I been able to find it again

Edit 1: I saw this movie around 7-10 years ago, I saw it in a channel like Cinemax, I don't think it was much older

Edit 2: You actually never see the monsters, you only hear the noises of them walking/running around

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you see this film, and roughly when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: You said monsters drag people into the light, can you remember what they look like? Insects? Reptiles? Teddy bears?

Comment: Kinda sounds vaguely like Skyline released in 2010